# Перевод сайта со статических страниц на динамические

Tags: seo

Здравствуйте! Большая часть страниц сайта представляет сейчас из себя с статичные хтмл страницы с  урл такого типа: www.site.ru/nazvanie-tovara.html. По некоторым запросам сайт находится на первых позициях в поиске, при этом ключевые слова запросов присутствуют в URL страниц.   Сейчас осуществляем переход на страницы, генерируемые php скриптом (т.е. скрипт будет всего один, просто в зависимости от урл он будет выдавать разный контент). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сделать, что бы при переходе не потерять в посещаемости? И не повлияет ли на позиции в поиске то, что мы уберем из адресов .html, т.е. сделаем url вида www.site.ru/nazvanie-tovara

Comment: Используйте mod_rewrite и генерируйте ссылки в таком же виде, как они выглядели на статическом сайте

Comment: @Mariya, а что вообще вас заставляет отказаться от старой схемы в URL? Никто же не мешает по адресу /товар.html отдавать всё то же самое, что и по адресу /товар в "новой" схеме. Более того, идеальным вариантом было бы генерировать страницы для товаров с помощью CMS, и отдавать их как статику, подргужая динамические элементы (например, рейтинг, "также покупали", корзину etc) ajax.

Comment: я просто думала, что отсутствие расширений добавит удобства и безопасности, но, в принципе, можно оставить и старые URL, конечно. Страницы уже сейчас генерируются cms, в данный момент я думаю, как лучше осуществлять внедрение новой системы, потому что БД будет заполняться постепенно, т.е. потребуется какой-то плавный переход от статики к динамически генерируемым страницам. Да я еще  и плохо разбираюсь в перенаправлении страниц, пока разбираюсь только, как надо сделать, т.е. получается, что потом, при использовании уже динамических страниц мне будет необходимо при обращении к адресу

Comment: www.site.ru/tovar.htm перенаправить сначала на общий скрипт, генерирующий хтмл и потом как-то снова выдать статический урл?

Comment: Если у вас в новой системе товары будут отдаваться по адресам вида site.ru/tovar (и "tovar" соответствует предыдущему адресу site.ru/tovar.html), то чтобы не лезть в дебри - достакточно просто сделать перенаправление в .htaccess:

    RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ /$1

Если адреса (старый и новый) не соответствуют друг другу, то это уже совсем другой разговор...

Comment: Была у вас ссылка на статическую страницу site.ru/catalog/porsche_cayenne.html. Оставляете такуюже ссылку, но все запросы перенаправляете на морду сайта, где подключен скрипт обработки запроса. 

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]

В этом скрипте парсите URL и выдаете соответствующий товар.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если при запросе страницы  www.site.ru/nazvanie-tovara.html поисковик получит 404 ошибку, он выкинет страницу из индекса, позиция будет потеряна, ссылочная масса также, поэтому позиции рухнут. Также пройдет время пока он найдет страницу www.site.ru/nazvanie-tovara, добавит её в выдачу, наберется ссылочная масса, и только потом она появится в выдаче, естественно не в топе.

Резюмируя, нужно настроить Mod Rewrite с 301 редирект-ом, тогда поисковик очень аккуратно склеит страницы и проблем не будет.